# Postman Mongoose response empty array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, postman

I am working on an app that responses are set like

```
req.data = data
```

I created a new endpoint, and if I `console.log` the data, I can see that mongoose is retriving the data. But postman is showing an empty array in the response

Also if I add

```
res.json(data)
```

Postman will show the json, but I don't want to change the app style

Probably I forgot to set something

Comment: You should also mention the http server framework/library you are using

Comment: thank you @TheeSritabtim I am using express. I did a test with mocha and there I have the data. postman is not showing, perhaps I forgot something in postman

Comment: Responding using `req` is a bit strange. Are you sure you mean `req.data` not `res.data`?
From express API reference https://expressjs.com/en/api.html There is no reference about `req.data` or even `res.data`, you might be confused with other library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually i use express to make API responses as the following :

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
 // some code goes here that will return DATA
 res.status(200).json(DATA) // And This line will return a JSON file to postman
})
```

NOTE : use `req.something` to handle your incoming data, `res.something` to make a response to the client.